# How to compare values in database with part of a string

Tags: php, mysql

In my database there are 3 card names :

```
vampire's curse
vampire lord
shadow vampire
```

I created a search form. It will search for cards that contains letters user typed. For example    3 values in my database. If user type "vampire" then press submit, it will show up the values.But it don't know how to compare value in database with a part of a string. Here my code ( I haven't finished yet).

search_form.php

```
<?php
echo "<h2> Search your card </h2>";
echo "<h3> type your card name fully or partly here </h3>";
echo "<form action='SearchData.php' method='POST'>";
echo "Card name (full or part) <input type='text' name='CardName'/>";
echo "<input type='submit' values='search for card(s)'/>";
?>
```

SearchData.php

```
<?php
include('connect.inc');
$connect=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname) or die("can't connect to server");
if(isset($_POST['CardName']) and !empty($_POST['CardName']))
{    
    $data=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['CardName']);
    $query="SELECT CardName FROM dragon WHERE CardName='";
    // Iam stucked at here !        
}
else
{
    echo "search form can not be empty !";
    include("search_form.php");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [the `LIKE` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

```
SELECT id, name FROM cards WHERE name LIKE '%vampire%';
```

Answer (score 1):

For the reference, you can also use [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) if you want.

```
SELECT id, name FROM cards WHERE name REGEXP 'vampire';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$search = "%".$_POST['search']."%";
        $read = new mysqli($db_hostname,$db_rUsername,$db_rPassword,$db_database);
        $stmt = $read->prepare("SELECT `CardName` FROM dragon WHERE `cardname` LIKE ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$search);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($cardnameDb);
        while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
            $cardName[] = $cardnameDB;
        }
        $stmt->close();
```

This returns an array of cards which match the searched term.

Note that the search term has % before and after it, this just acts like a wildcard. I have a non prepared statement one too if you would like to see it however it's not recommended that you use this.

If you have any questions feel free to ask me! Note that he `LIKE` operator is what you are looking for.